# how to Remove object from list based on certain condition (java)?

Tags: java

am trying to find a way to remove an object from a list based on a condition, the object is a patient that have an age attribute, i want to remove every patient that is older than 25 age from a list,  the code consist of 4 lists that is categorized based on certain info any way here is my code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flag = true;
   
    System.out.print("Enter number of patients: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    
    AList patients  = new AList(n); //All Patients
    AList Apatients = new AList(); //category "A" Patients
    AList Bpatients = new AList(); //category "B" Patients
    AList Cpatients = new AList(); //category "C" Patients
   
    //Add Patients to the list:
    for(int i =0; i < n ; i++){
        Patients p = new Patients();
        System.out.print("Enter Patient name: ");
        p.name = kb.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("Enter Patient ID: ");
        p.id = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Patient Age: ");
        p.age = in.nextInt();            
        
        flag = true;
        while(flag){
            System.out.print("Enter Patient Category: ");
            p.category = kb.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            if(p.category.equals("a") || p.category.equals("A")){
                Apatients.add(p);
                flag = false;
            }
            else if(p.category.equals("b") || p.category.equals("B")){
                Bpatients.add(p);
                flag = false;
            }
            else if(p.category.equals("c") || p.category.equals("C")){
                Cpatients.add(p);
                flag = false;
                
            }
            else{
               System.out.println("Wrong Entry...! Try Again");
            }
        }
        patients.add(p);
    }    
    //Display all patients:
    System.out.println("All Patients information : ");
    patients.display();
    
    System.out.println("Category A Patients : ");
    Apatients.display();
    
    System.out.println("Category B Patients : ");
    Bpatients.display();
    
    System.out.println("Category C Patients : ");
    Cpatients.display();
    
    //From the list for A category remove each patient with age > 25 year:
    for(int i=0; i < Apatients.getLength();){
        // here is my problem how to iterate the list and check for any patient age > 25 to remove it? 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is an `AList`?

Comment: Why are you using 2 scanners, when you just have to take input from the user.

Comment: When a patient's information is entered, why not test the entered age at that point, and only add the patient to the appropriate lists based on age?

Comment: @Steve AList is not core of java it is a data structured by me.

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya i know using two Scanners one for text and other for numbers is not professional but i am still learning actually thanks for the note

Answer (score 2):

You have many, many bugs in this code.

### 2 scanners

You should have only one Scanner object. Why do you have both `kb` and `in`? Delete one.

### mixing `nextLine` and `nextAnythingElse`

You can't mix those. The usual thing to do is to never use `nextLine()`; to read a line of text, just use `next()`. This does require that you update the scanner's delimiter; immediately after making the scanner object, call `in.useDelimiter("\r?\n");` on it.

### AList isn't a thing

Whatever might 'AList' be? It's not in core java and it doesn't sound like it is required here; just use `ArrayList<Patient>` instead

### naming a class with a plural name.

Clearly a single `Patients` instance represents a single patient, therefore, you should call it `Patient`, because what you have is clearly confusing you.

### You're breaking with convention.

`thisIsAVariableName`, `ThisIsATypeName`, `THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT`. That should be `aPatients`, not `APatients`. This makes your code hard to read, and given that you're using a community resource (Stack Overflow), that's not good.

### Your actual question

Given that AList is not a thing and you didn't paste it, it is not possible for anybody on SO to answer this question. Update the question and include the API of `AList`, or stop using it (there is no reason to use this, unless it is mandated because this is homework, in which case, you should ask your teacher for help on this; they get paid, and are the ones who are supposed to support this `AList` class you're using). Had you been using ArrayList, there are a number of ways to do this. But first a concern: If you loop through each item by way of 'index', then removing an element shifts all indexes down by one, which makes the math complicated. One extremely easy way out of that dilemma is to loop through the list backwards to forwards, because then the shifting of indices doesn't have an impact.

### Option #1: Iterators

```
var it = aPatients.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Patient p = it.next();
    if (p.getAge() > 25) it.remove();
}
```

### Option #2: Backwards loop

```
for (int i = aPatients.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (aPatients.get(i).getAge() > 25) aPatients.remove(i);
}
```

### Option #3: removeIf

```
aPatients.removeIf(pat -> pat.getAge() > 25);
```

Comment: First of all let me thank you for all these useful information it took time from you and i appreciate that, am still a beginner and still learning in this case stack overflow should welcome my question also if i was asking my question in a wrong way it is enough to clarify for me that i am asking in wrong way without prejudgments , I am an IT manager in a studios company and am interested in desktop app development, and now am learning how to create a datatypes on my own (data structuring), thats why i m using a data type i created called AList

Comment: The field of "Development", I have employees that i have put to create apps, i am only learning programming because it is interesting and to debug a code that the employees under my responsibility have developed nothing more, so i hope we don't judge each other and am not challenging any one here i am just asking a question, anyway thank you for your answer i will take what is good on it.